# method of an object in index controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

This is a really simple question, but for some reason I cannot find the solution.

My controller is:

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
  #I want something here for a single event
  distance = Time.now.to_date.distance_to(@event.event_date)
  @days = distance[:days]
  @months = distance[:months]
  @years = distance[:years]
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.event_date %></td>
        <td> Just  <%= @days %> days, <%= @months %> months and <%= @years %> years for the event </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course it doesn't work because there is no @event.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is add that functionality to individual records
I would add `distance` as a method on the `Event` class

so

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #... your model code here

  def distance
    Time.now.to_date.distance_to(self.event_date)
  end
end
```

the controller

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
end
```

and in the view

```
<td> Just  <%= event.distance[:days] %> days, <%= event.distance[:months] %> months and <%= event.distance[:years] %> years for the event </td>
```

You could add some more methods to your model to make it prettier like `event.distance_days` or something but I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

"I want something here for a single event."

The default way to find single records is by id:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

But to me, it should work like that because I don't see `@event` called in the view.